How do I access sftp with nautilus with RSA
I realize that we used to be able to use sftp://@IPADDRESS:PORT/ directly into nautilus

But this is now broken because of some RSA something or other.
What am I supposed to do?  Please explain like I'm 5.

What do you mean by "some RSA something or the other"?
